# Example of product topology where the index set is uncountable

Tags: general-topology, definition, product-space

I'm reading through Munkres, chapter 2, section 19 (Product topology).
I can't see any example of product topology where the family of space is indexed with an uncountable set.

Can you provide an example which is maybe easy to understand, maybe with some analogy with $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What about $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: I struggle to find an example of element of such space, how do you represent such elements? for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a tuple of real numbers, what would be an element of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Comment: We frequently denote $\mathbb{R}^X$ as the class of all functions $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Don't think about tuples. Think instead about functions. For example, $\mathbb R^n$ is just the set of all functions $\{1,...,n\} \mapsto \mathbb R$ (i.e. length $n$ sequences of real numbers). Extending further, $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is the set of all functions $\mathbb N \mapsto \mathbb R$ (i.e. infinite sequences of real numbers). Similarly $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ is the set of all functions $\mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$; the sequence analogy does not help here, although we are all familiar enough with the set of functions $\mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. You take any family of spaces $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ over uncountable $I$ and then you take the product $\prod X_i$. What other example are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I guess we can do the following (I hope this fits your expectation):

for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$ define the set $X_r = \{x_r, y_r\}$ (two different points).

Define $X = \prod_{r \in \mathbb{R}}X_r$.

If we give each $X_r$ the discrete topology (and so it becomes Hausdorff), then $X$ is a topological space with either the box topology, or the product topology.

An interesting fact about this construction is that in the box topology, this $X$, given that each $X_r$ is Hausdorff, is not compact.

Comment: In the box topology of course $X$ is discrete and thus non-compact. Easier argument.